# In a distributed system is it possible for both parties to simultaneously agree a message exchange was made?

Tags: distributed-systems

Given that the two generals problema is unsolvable, which means that both parties involved cannot agree that both know something, i ask something simpler.  Is it possible for both parties to agree that a message Exchange occurred? In other words, is it possible for both parties to agree that a "conversation" occurred?

For instance, if A and B communicate with messages Mx

```
A -M1 -> B
A <-M2 - B
A -M3 -> B
```

At this point B knows that a message Exchange occurred, but can he be sure that A also knows so?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Guarantee under what circumstances? You can only give guarantees against a particular kind of adversary. For example,if your model has perfectly reliable channels, all A needs to do is send a message to B: A knows it was received because the channel is perfectly reliable; B knows it was received because he received it. But if the channel is unreliable or even potentially malicious, we're back in the two generals problem.

Answer (score 3):

I think it *is* the "two general" problem.

The "two general" problem is informally stated as follows [1]:

> The commanding general of the first division wishes to coordinate a simultaneous attack. The generals can ***communicate only by means of messengers***. Normally, it takes a messenger one hour to get from one encampment to the other. However, it is possible that he will get lost in the dark or, worse yet, be captured by the enemy.

What is the difference between this and your "message-exchanging" problem?

---

[1] [Reasoning about Knowledge](https://mitpress.mit.edu/index.php?q=books/reasoning-about-knowledge). By Ronald Fagin, Joseph Y. Halpern, Yoram Moses and Moshe Vardi.